# Error System.NullReferenceException

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5, oracle-11g

Estoy haciendo un sistema de asistencia, y estoy pasando la lista Model que esta ubicada en el `foreach` de la Vista.

Esa lista la va recibir el controlador "**`TomarAsistencia`**" en un parámetro, luego va a pasar por otro `foreach` que viene a ser del controlador, al momento de ejecutar el sistema se cae, ya que esa lista aparece como vacío. Y el resultado es el siguiente error:

> **"System.NullReferenceException"**

que en otras palabras es un `NULL`. Quisiera saber que puedo hacer para evitar ese `null`.

**Vista**

```
@model IEnumerable<wsCharlas.Models.ClsInteresado>

@{
    /**/

    ViewBag.Title = "Listar Inscritos";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Listar Inscritos:</h2>
<h6>Aquí usted podrá colocar todos los datos respectivos de la charla que desee crear.</h6>

<hr />

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h6>Buscar Interesado: </h6>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre de un interesado" class="form-control" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="Buscar" />
    <br />
}

<hr />

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Guardar Asistencia", "TomarAsistencia", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }, new { listaInteresados = Model })
    @Html.ActionLink("Regresar", "MostraCharlas", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
</div>

<hr />

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.dni_Inter)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.apePat_Inter)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.apeMat_Inter)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.nombres_Inter)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.asistencia_Inter)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dni_Inter)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.apePat_Inter)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.apeMat_Inter)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombres_Inter)
            </td>
            <td class="td-asistencia">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.asistencia_Inter)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Guardar Asistencia", "TomarAsistencia", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }, new { listaInteresados = Model})
    @Html.ActionLink("Regresar", "MostraCharlas", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary"})
</div>

<style>

    .container {
        max-width: 1250px;
    }

    .td-asistencia {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

**Controlador**

```
//REGISTRAR ASISTENCIA
    public ActionResult TomarAsistencia(IEnumerable<ClsInteresado>listaInteresados)
    {

        foreach (var item in listaInteresados)
        {
            ClsConexion con = new ClsConexion();
            var Cnx = con.Conexion();

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SIMEXA_SP_TOMAR_ASISTENCIA", Cnx);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_id_asis", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = item.ID_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_dni_asis", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = item.dni_Inter;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("param_desc_asis", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = item.asistencia_Inter;
            Cnx.Open();

            OracleTransaction tx = Cnx.BeginTransaction();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            tx.Commit();

            Cnx.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
            Cnx.Dispose();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("MostraCharlas");

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes validar si es null primero. O usar esto:

```
@foreach (var item in Model ??  Enumerable.Empty<wsCharlas.Models.ClsInteresado>()){

}
```

o

```
if(Model != null)
{
}
```

Comment: Genial, gracias por la ayuda ;)